# Error installing SQL Server 2014 Express or SSMS to PC with Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, installation

I am trying to install the SQL Server 2014 express edition onto my PC which has Visual Studio 2013 community edition installed. with both the express edition or just the management studio, I am getting the following error which results in a rollback. Does anyone have an idea what is happening?

Thank you

> ### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Setup
>
> The following error has occurred:
>
> An error occurred during the installation of assembly
>   'policy.8.0.Microsoft.VC80.ATL,version="8.0.50727.4053",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="x86",type="win32-policy"'.
>   Please refer to Help and Support for more information. HRESULT:
>   0x800736B3.
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.2000.8&EvtType=0xDF039760%25401201%25401
>
> ------------------------------ BUTTONS:
>
> ### OK

Comment: I'm getting this same error. It almost looks like it is detecting that my PC is 32-bit or the downloaded installer is only for 32-bit (*processorArchitecture="x86"*). Did you ever solve this?